# How to use a nested enum correctly? [Java]

Tags: java, enums, nested

I want to implement hand ranges in poker, which basically is a set of two cards (=hand).
Since a range can hold a lot of hands, I wanted to create "default" ranges and adapt my range from there. I though about doing it the following way:

- Range class that holds the hands of my range

- Create an inner enum for the predefined ranges

Is there a better way to do it? I nested the enum inside the range class to improve the readability through the path Range.Predefined.*. Nonetheless it feels a little bit clumsy, especially the part where I set up my range.

```
public class Range{
    ArrayList<Hand> range;

    public Range(ArrayList<Hand> r){
        this.range = r;
    }

    public void addHandToRange(Hand hand){
        //add a hand to range
    }
    public void removeHandFromRange(Hand hand){
        //remove a hand from range
    }
    
    public enum Predefined{
        RANGE_1, RANGE_2, RANGE_3;
        ArrayList<Hand> predefinedRange;

        //some code to set up predefined ranges 1-3

        public ArrayList<Hand> getRange() {
            //getRange
        }
    }
}
```

Then I could set up my range something like this with a predefined range and go from there (but lots of code and only using the enum for its method...):

```
Range myRange = new Range(Range.Predefined.RANGE_1.getRange());
```

I'd rather have a solution like the following. This would require to change "Range" into the Enum type, which I don't want to do (since Range should remain mutable - and mutable enums should be avoided).

```
Range myRange = PredefinedRange.RANGE_1;
```

Am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use enum at all?

You could just have the Range class keep a few public static final Range variables around.

```
public class Range{
  public static final Range TOP_PAIR_RANGE = new Range(...)
  public static final Range SUITED_CONNECTOR_RANGE = new Range(...)
  public static final Range ACE_SUITED_RANGE = new Range(...)
  ...
}
```

Then just reference it

```
Range myRange = Range.TOP_PAIR_RANGE;
```

Comment: You are right, constants of the same type is an alternative. In fact, it is exactly how enums are implemented (beside the private constructor), but it doesn't separate (the code for) my private range from the predefined ranges as well. It also doesn't document as well, which predefined ranges are available.